# Dynamically load javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var _scriptUrl = [
    'vendor/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
    'vendor/angular/angular.js',
    'vendor/angular/angular-cookies.js',
    'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
]

var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
jsElm.type = "application/javascript";

for(var i = 0; i < _scriptUrl.length; i++)
{
    jsElm.src = _scriptUrl[i];
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```

But it is always appending last one only, please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try appending the child in the loop.  In your example, you only have one instance of script.

```
for(var i = 0; i<_scriptUrl.length; i++)
{
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = _scriptUrl[i];
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```

If you're serious about async loading of js, try [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring the `jsElm` outside of your `for` loop, therefore referencing the same element on each iteration. Move this declaration inside your for loop:

```
var _scriptUrl = [
    'vendor/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
    'vendor/angular/angular.js',
    'vendor/angular/angular-cookies.js',
    'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
]

for (var i = 0; i < _scriptUrl.length; i++) {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = _scriptUrl[i];
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a single `<script>` and then changing its `src` rapidly so that only the last one has enough time to load.

Create the script element **inside** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are always update the `jsElm.src`.

```
for(var i= 0;i<_scriptUrl.length;i++)
{
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = _scriptUrl[i];
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```